# "Do this" or "Will this" in questions

Tags: questions

I have a question sentence:

"Will this set of vectors form an orthogonal basis for the system?".

Is it ok to start with "Will this" or "Do this" is more appropriate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should prefer *Does this... ?*.  (**Not** *Do this... ?*.)

In general, Math is about things that are eternally true. It exists outside of time. We use the present simple for talking about such things.

There are circumstances when *will* is more appropriate. For instance:

> If I use this method described to obtain a set of vectors, will it form an orthogonal basis?

But these are exceptional.

Comment: Why the switch from considering the vectors as a set (_Does_ this... form an orthogonal basis) to considering them individually (... will _they_ form an orthogonal basis)? I've no problem conceptually, but this licenses 'Do this set of vectors' according to notional concord.

Comment: Good catch! I was making the some mistake as in the original question: switching between treating a set as singular and plural.